# HABTM multi "and" query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have Article and Tag records with HABTM relation.

I need to filter Article by array of tags with "and" query.

With tags below, I need every "Salami" and "Pizza" that are expired.

**tags = ["Salami", "Pizza", "Expired"]** // items could be any number from 1..n

I came up with following but this returns every "Salami" and "Pizza" which aren't expired.  This also return every items expired which aren't Salami nor Pizza

```
def tags_query
    render status: 200, json: Article.includes(:tags).where('tags.name' => params[:tags] )
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you actually want to query with "and" for all tags you could do it like this:

```
required_tags = ["Salami", "Pizza", "Expired"]

Article.joins(:tags)
       .where(tags: { name: required_tags })
       .group('articles.id')
       .having('count(*) = ?', required_tags.count)
```

What it does is:

- Get all articles that have tags which contain one of the required tags
- Group them, so that we have for example a group of 3 when the article has the tags "Salami", "Pizza" and "Expired", or just a group of 2 when the article has the tags "Salami", "Pizza" and "Fish".
- Then only take those groups with as many members as specified in our required tags array.

Comment: the only issue I see here is that the logic is actually `(salami || pizza) && expired` ?   that's pseudocode to display the logic...

Comment: You are probably right. In this case my answer is wrong and will only return Articles that are expired Salami Pizzas.

Comment: I think you're on the right path. you could turn your where to be an OR with the first two tags then chain another where for the expired tag? The OR would have to be a SQL string, which I flee from in horror in my ActiveRecord code. You could use Arel syntax to achieve the OR, but that's decidedly more complicated.

Comment: This answer is exactly what I needed, apologize for putting confusing tags example...

Comment: This isn't working properly when using Japanese characters as tags.  Ex. if tags were "東京"(Tokyo) and "スイーツ"(Sweets), the result would contain "Tokyo" but does not contain "Sweets" and event there are records contains both "Tokyo" and "Sweets", they aren't shown on result.  Any idea why and how to fix the issue?